# Self-Hosted Web API - Referenced Controllers Don't Work with "Optimize Code" Option

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, compiler-optimization

I have an ASP.NET Web API project hosted in a Windows Service, using OWIN. I'm using a Startup class that configures some things, and am using the IAppBuilder.UseWebApi() option. Everything works perfectly in the debugger and from the command line (I use a command line argument of -e to run in console, or it can run as a Windows Service).

Everything is working great, BUT, when I build in Release mode with the build option enabled for "Optimize Code", my service controllers don't seem to work.

I have my controller in a separate class library, and I'm using this line to probe the controller on application start, as suggested here: [Self-hosting WebAPI application referencing controller from different assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988749/self-hosting-webapi-application-referencing-controller-from-different-assembly)

```
var controllerType = typeof(MetricsController);
```

I have a feeling that the Optimize Code option causes the compiler to ignore this line. Does anyone have any insight or ideas about how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried turning off code optimization when you compile? Did everything work as expected when you did that?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman I did actually. When I turn off Code Optimization, it works as expected. I don't know much about Code Optimization; do you know if it's worth disabling to fix this issue? Or maybe there's a way to have the optimization ignore this line somehow? I'll do some more looking. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

After working with this for a bit, I implemented the following approach which the Optimize Code option seems to be happy with.

Class-level member:

```
private readonly List<Type> _controllers = new List<Type>();
```

Then in my Startup.Configuration method, I replaced this:

```
// Hack: This forces a manual probe of the controller assembly
var controllerType = typeof(MyController);
```

With this:

```
// Better Hack: This forces a manual probe of the controller assembly
_controllers.Add(typeof(MyController));
```

What seems to be happening is that the Optimize Code option is stripping out logic that is declared but never used. In this case, I was using the original hack to probe the assembly so the application knows about its existence. Since it was so tightly scoped and the variable `controllerType` was never used, the compiler ignores it. The new approach is probably just enough of a hint that it *may* be used that the compiler keeps it.

I tried a reflection-based approach but could not get it to work. I even manually loaded the assembly having the controllers, and I could see it loaded in the AppDomain when debugging, but for some reason it still wouldn't work. I could even verify that the List was populated with the controller types, but strangely no luck. Definitely open to any suggestions on this since I will be using a similar approach in the future on another project.